# Using Checkboxes with HTML and PHP (SQLite Database)

Tags: php, html, sqlite, checkbox, fetch

I am trying to set the value of my checkbox. I do have a SQLite database with a table with some rows. Some rows contain `STATUS = 1`, some contain `STATUS = 0`.

```
... "STATUS" BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, ...
```

So I check the current row with the fetchArray function and everything else works fine, but in my HTML site, all checkboxes are checked. Is there a logical mistake?

```
while ($row = $table->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $output .= '<tr>';

    if ($row['STATUS'] == 1) {
        $output .= '<td class="STATUS" data-id1="' . $row['ID'] . '" bgcolor="#cecece"><input type="checkbox" name="STATUS" checked="true"></td>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<td class="STATUS" data-id1="' . $row['ID'] . '" bgcolor="#cecece"><input type="checkbox" name="STATUS" checked="false"></td>';
    }

    $output .= '<td class="USER" data-id2="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['USER'] . '</td>
                ...
                <td class="DESCRIPTION" data-id11="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . '</td>
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_edit" data-id12="' . $row['ID'] . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-block btn_edit">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_delete" data-id13="' . $row['ID'] . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-block btn_delete">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>';
}
```

Comment: depending on data type on the status?  have you tried    == '1'  instead of ==1

Comment: STATUS is boolean (true/false -> 1/0). I tried ==, ===, 1, '1', "1"... Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
if ($row['STATUS'] == 1) {
    $output .= '<td class="STATUS" data-id1="' . $row['ID'] . '" bgcolor="#cecece"><input type="checkbox" name="STATUS" checked>' . $row['STATUS'] . '</td>';
}
else {
    $output .= '<td class="STATUS" data-id1="' . $row['ID'] . '" bgcolor="#cecece"><input type="checkbox" name="STATUS">' . $row['STATUS'] . '</td>';
}
```

As you can see, I just changed the syntax of the HTML code. I don't know why the `checked` property has to be used like this, but to be honest I don't really care. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Hariboo! :-)